# how to switch focus to different application C++ / WinAPI

Tags: c++

I want to set focus to a particular user-application (using process name) but from the code running "in background" not from the active process. I need to catch a global event and react by bringing the specific application to the front.

Preconditions:

- application 1 working on top
- application 2 working but not active
- my application 3 working but not active, just running to handle the issue

Actions:

- my application 3 detects a particular Windows event (e.g. mouse double click)
- it triggers application 2 to go foreground

Expected:

- application 2 is now active and the focus is on it

Neither `SetForegroundWindow()` nor `SwitchToThisWindow()` works because my app is not the active one to trigger switch. It must trigger it "from the background" at any time. Does anybody have the solution? The sample of exemplary code would be very appreciated.

[EDITED]: I found a kind of solution - I use `AttachThreadInput()` function and put as parameters `GetWindowThreadProcessId()` of window to be active as first and `GetCurrentThreadID()` as second parameter. OF course `TRUE` as third. Than both `SetActiveWindow()` and `SetForegroundWindow()` work but... unfortunatelly only while debuging in Visual Studio (2013). When I run .exe file both in Debug and Release version, focus does not fire. Does anyone have an idea why it is so?

Comment: Microsoft is very serious about not allowing un-focused processes to set focus.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, I have found a workaround on the net. I send `Alt` key as input to the system. Then I can use `SetForegroundWindow()` successufully. After that the `Alt` key should be released of course.

```
//set up a generic keyboard event
INPUT keyInput;
keyInput.type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
keyInput.ki.wScan = 0; //hardware scan code for key
keyInput.ki.time = 0;
keyInput.ki.dwExtraInfo = 0;

//set focus to the hWnd (sending Alt allows to bypass limitation)
keyInput.ki.wVk = VK_MENU;
keyInput.ki.dwFlags = 0;   //0 for key press
SendInput(1, &keyInput, sizeof(INPUT));
           
SetForegroundWindow(hWnd); //sets the focus 

keyInput.ki.wVk = VK_MENU;
keyInput.ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;  //for key release
SendInput(1, &keyInput, sizeof(INPUT));
```